# SVG animation doesn't run on IE9/IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, animation, svg

Hi I have a piece of `HTML` code which basically does an SVG animation. This works fine in Chrome as well as Firefox but not in IE9/IE10.

Any solution?

Need single codebase which works at least in Chrome/Firefox/IE 9 and above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>

<body>

    <div id='svgnotsupported' style='visibility: hidden;'>
        <h1>This application requires SVG support</h1>
    </div>

    <div id='svgsupported' style='visibility: hidden'></div>

    <script>

        var svgsupport;

        window.onload = function supportsSvg() {

            var ua = navigator.userAgent;
            var M = ua.match(/(chrome)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
            var b =   document.implementation.hasFeature("http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#BasicStructure",  "1.0")
            if(b || M) {
                svgsupport = document.getElementById('svgsupported');
            } else {
                svgsupport = document.getElementById('svgnotsupported');
            }

            svgsupport.style.visibility = 'visible';

        }

    </script>

    <svg id="no_fewer_than_N_events_E_between_event_Q_and_first_R_thereafter" width="588" height="578" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <defs>
            <marker id="Triangle" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="20" refY="10" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
                <path d="M 0 0 L 20 10 L 0 20 z" fill="blue"/>
            </marker>
            <marker id="Circle" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="5" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
                <circle cx="5" cy="5"  r="3" fill="blue"/>
            </marker>
        </defs>
        <g>
            <path id="_4JpShw3P09cVj6Vb1lR041" d="M 399.0,228.0 a 20.0 40.0, 0, 1, 0, 54.0 0.0" style="fill:none;stroke:blue ;stroke-width:3" marker-end="url(#Triangle)" />
            <rect id="anim_4JpShw3P09cVj6Vb1lR041" x="-5" y="-5" width="10" height="10" fill="red">
            <animateMotion  path="M 399.0,228.0 a 20.0 40.0, 0, 1, 0, 54.0 0.0" dur="5s" rotate="auto" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="1s"  />
            </rect> 
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect id="_0uuE73jF5kmqe14s6Y02NF" x="372" y="165" rx="10.0" ry="6.0" width="109" height="63" style="fill:white;stroke:black;stroke-width:4;opacity:0.5">
                <animate id="anim_0uuE73jF5kmqe14s6Y02NF" attributeName="stroke" attributeType="CSS" from="lime" to="black" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite" />
            </rect>
        </g>
    </svg>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the [FakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/) library to add animation support to IE.

Comment: How to use fakeSMIL? any idea or link i can go through?

Comment: Robert thanks for your reply. I have downloaded smil.use.js file and reference added in my html file but still its not working IE. my question do i have to change SMIL based svg tags in my html file or i have to run this html file on local web server?

Comment: The example from @RobertLongson does not animate for me when I view it in IE9.

Comment: In order to make this work in IE9 you have to include the script like this in the head: http://jsfiddle.net/FG3PG/206/

Comment: Good solution! However, it is not working when I use `svg` with `src` in `<img>` tag

Comment: Well there's no scripting in an `<img>` tag and fakeSmile is a script so it won't run. There's no possibility of any solution therefore for  `<img>` tag SMIL on IE given that.