# Animate Chartist on show

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js, chartist.js

I like the features of Chartist:
https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/

But I would like Chartist to animate a pie chart in the same cool way ChartJS does when the chart is shown, like this:
http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads7/easily-create-stunning-animated-charts-with-chart-js/chartjs-demo.html

I read you can somehow add CSS anims to Chartist, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is provided in Chartist using SMIL - http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/examples.html#svg-path-animation.

While this will work as is in Chrome - you'll probably need a shim for IE - [SVG animation not working IE9/IE10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738752/svg-animation-not-working-ie9-ie10)

---

Here is a rather silly bounce implementation (it looks more like pacman, but it should be easy enough to figure out the right reverse and durations with a little trial and error; or you could cheat and check out the easeOutBounce implementation in Chart.js code)

```
var data = {
    series: [5, 3, 14]
};

var chart = new Chartist.Pie('.pie', data, {
    donut: true,
    donutWidth: 194,
});

chart.on('draw', function (data) {
    if (data.type === 'slice') {
        // Get the total path length in order to use for dash array animation
        var pathLength = data.element._node.getTotalLength();

        // Set a dasharray that matches the path length as prerequisite to animate dashoffset
        data.element.attr({
            'stroke-dasharray': pathLength + 'px ' + pathLength + 'px'
        });

        // Create animation definition while also assigning an ID to the animation for later sync usage
        var animationDefinition = {
            'stroke-dashoffset': {
                id: 'anim' + data.index,
                dur: 500 * data.value / data.totalDataSum,
                from: -pathLength + 'px',
                to: '0px',
                // We need to use `fill: 'freeze'` otherwise our animation will fall back to initial (not visible)
                fill: 'freeze'
            }
        };

        // If this was not the first slice, we need to time the animation so that it uses the end sync event of the previous animation
        if (data.index !== 0) {
            animationDefinition['stroke-dashoffset'].begin = 'anim' + (data.index - 1) + '.end';
        }

        // We need to set an initial value before the animation starts as we are not in guided mode which would do that for us
        data.element.attr({
            'stroke-dashoffset': -pathLength + 'px'
        });

        // We can't use guided mode as the animations need to rely on setting begin manually
        // See http://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/api-documentation.html#chartistsvg-function-animate
        data.element.animate(animationDefinition, false);

        // add (naive) bounce
        if (data.endAngle === 360) {
            var index = data.index;
            var dur = 1000 * data.value / data.totalDataSum / 2;
            var from = 0;
            var to = -pathLength / 3;

            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                data.element.animate({
                    'stroke-dashoffset': {
                        id: 'anim' + (index + 1),
                        dur: dur,
                        from: from + 'px',
                        to: to + 'px',
                        fill: 'freeze',
                        begin: 'anim' + index + '.end'
                    }
                }, false);

                index++;
                dur /= 1.75;

                var t = from;
                from = to;
                to = t / 2.5;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I know the question is answered, by I fiddled with this for some time now and I cannot create a smooth and nice pie chart anim just like the second link in my question. Do you have a link or an example?

Comment: Could you post what you have so far in a fiddle?

Comment: Pretty much have the basic example, tried several things in the 'draw' event, but couldn't get it to work. http://jsfiddle.net/gx55mo6b/1/

Comment: I'm afraid you won't get bounce and all easily, But you can use any bezier curve - http://jsfiddle.net/c6LuxLy9/. To change the animation function just add `easing:` followed by any of the strings in https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/blob/9d8c258fbfff8ba2450d73897455cff5151d5ad6/dist/chartist.js#L2187

Comment: Updated the answer. Give a shout if you need any help figuring out the code.

Comment: If the aim is to make this useful, then the bouncing effect compared to the one with ChartJS isn't very esthetically looking and the pie is not perfectly circular, it looks kinda wavy. But I cannot ask you to put more time into this, many thanx for your efforts!

Comment: I'll give it another shot sometime this week - the effect was more of a proof of concept. It was fun figuring it out :-)